# Javascript prompts and variables

Tags: javascript, variables

I've learnt C# (i think it was c# at least...) in the past and our UNI assignment requires us to work in javascript to produce code within a HTML document that uses an input value and determines what type of soil it is.

My code isnt working. Its something to do with this section.

```
    var soilsize = 20;
    var valid = false;

    while (valid = false){                                                     //do while valid is false
        var soilsize = prompt("Please enter soil size in millimetres");
        if (soilsize = null) || (isNaN(soilsize)) || (soilsize <0) {        // if nothing was entered, if the entered value is not a number, or if size is < 0
            prompt("This is not a positive number.");
            var valid = false;
        }
        else{
            var valid = true;
        }
    }
```

Do i still need to predefine the variables? 
Any help is appreciated. I can upload the full code if needed. Thanks lads.

Comment: The problem is in your `while (valid = false)` and `if (soilsize = null)`. In JavaScript, one equals sign **assigns** -- you need two to **compare** (and you can use three for strict comparison).

Comment: Also the same problem for the `while` block. It never enters the loop. You can change it to `while(valid)` but initialize it with `true` and invert the values inside the `if` block with: `valid = true`, don't set `var valid` again.

Other things: Your if block is not well formatted, change to: `if (soilsize == null || (isNaN(soilsize) || (soilsize <0))) { ...`

Comment: Not to mention the syntax errors… please read the docs on [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your correct code would be:

```
var valid = false;

while (!valid) {                                                     //do while valid is false
    var soilsize = prompt("Please enter soil size in millimetres");
    if (soilsize == null || (isNaN(soilsize) || (soilsize <0))) {        // if nothing was entered, if the entered value is not a number, or if size is < 0
        alert("This is not a positive number.");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        valid = true;
    }
}
```

But remember that by doing this you will never be able to leave without a valid value, also the alert won't be displayed since you'll re-ask for the soilsize value.

Answer (score -3):

You’ve already declared soilsize and valid. You shouldn’t redefine them with var in the whole loop.

Comment: There are tons of syntactic and semantic errors, but the redeclaration doesn’t make a difference, since there’s no function to provide an additional nested scope for `var` variables.